# Best Practice for Azure Ubuntu VM Firewall Internal IPs

Tags: azure, ubuntu-18.04

I have multiple VM's on an Azure VNet and would like to use the internal IP addresses for communication. I do not want to open endpoints in the Azure Portal.  I ran the UFW commands

sudo ufw allow from 10.0.0.0/16 to any port 8080 proto tcp
but noticed the UFW is disabled.

I am able to ping across the internal VNet but I'm not able to communicate over custom ports (8080, 5432, etc)

The boxes are Ubuntu 18.

Comment: the issues appeared to be with the custom services. Once I configured the bind ip listeners to 0.0.0.0 I was able to telnet to the ports needed internally.

Answer (score 0):

The issues appeared to be with the custom services. Once I configured the bind ip listeners to 0.0.0.0 I was able to telnet to the ports needed internally.